# How do I authenticate a web request from Unity to Node without requiring user credentials?

Tags: api, security, authentication, verify

I have a single player Unity game which records stats about game run-throughs, such as accuracy/runtime. I want these stats to be saved onto a web server / db so I can later aggregate them, the web server being a Node app using Express and the DB being a MongoDB instance. I have made the API routes to POST/GET the data but at the moment the routes are public. Normally, I would implement JWT whereby the user would have to login to be able to make web requests, but since the game is single player there is no login credentials to use.

What would be the best way to verify that a call to my web service has been made from within the Unity game without requiring the user to login/register an account?

So far I have thought about using a key on the Unity-side that needs to be sent through with each request, but this is prone to being discovered by searching through the source code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement oAuth on top of your REST API on the Node side. Now a caller has to provide an access token when calling your API. Make sure your implementation supports a flow you're going to choose in step 2. [oauth2authorize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) is a popular toolkit.
2. Choose an appropriate oAuth flow and implement it on the Unity side. One possibility is the [client credentials grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/), a flow designed for service-to-service calls. Another option is [exchanging JWT for an access token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523); the payload of the JWT can reflect the security context of the caller being the Unity game itself.